# Use external XSLT only for certain templates

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet, docbook

I want to import a XSLT stylesheet, but essentially to have it ignored by default, and only use its templates when called upon.

Our content contains custom XML + DocBook-style tables, so it's currently transformed by two XSLTs: XML => my.xsl => docbook.xsl => XHTML. Is it possible to do this all from my.xsl?

```
<!-- My XML -->
<xsl:template match="a"/>
<xsl:template match="b"/>
<xsl:template match="c"/>

<!-- DocBook XML -->
<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="docbook"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem with importing the docbook.xsl stylesheet is that it includes many other templates that interfere with existing templates. Ideally, there would be a way to import docbook.xsl into a specified mode, but that's not possible. Is there a way to do this without modifying docbook.xsl?

Answer (score 2):

Templates in the main stylesheet always have higher priority than templates from imported stylesheets. To avoid invoking the imported templates, simply override them in the main, in the required circumstances.

This should be the preferred technique. An alternative is:

1. Identify the match patterns where there is a potential conflict.
2. Use modes to discriminate between the two.
3. When you are invoking your templates with <xsl:apply-templates> on a selection which fits one of your identified overlapping patterns, use the appropriate mode (or no mode) to achieve your intended result (main template versus imported template).

Comment: @wst If you add an identity transform in the importing (main) stylesheet, the imported templates never get called unless you explicitly invoke the imported templates using xsl:apply-imports.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#modes)**.

In the imported stylesheet have all templates be in a mode with unique name that nobody uses. For example use `prefix:mymode` and have the prefix `prefix` bound to a namespace that belongs to you.

**To invoke processing from the imported stylesheet, use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$vNodesToBeProcessed" mode="prefix:mymode"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, docbook.xsl is a large module with multiple files and hundreds of templates, so it can't be easily modified to accommodate a mode. I tried regexing all of the files to add mode="docbook" to all of the templates, but it caused more problems.

Comment: @wst, Then use modes in your *primary* stylesheet module.